# Network Infrastructure Discovery

Tags: networking, network-monitor

Which software is suitable for creating a network map in Ubuntu or Windows?

The aim of my bachelor thesis is to describe methods of discovering devices on the local network and then creating a map of the computer network. I must create a network map, automatically discovering devices on the network in my college.

The map must be designed so that it can be continuously updated and edited.

- Software can work on Windows or Ubuntu.
- Should contain computers, laptops, switches, routers, printers in network.
- Format may be generated to export on Google Earth.

Software like op manager, solarwinds NPM, prtg network monitor, lanstate pro, anturis in Windows, cheops-ng, opennms in Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean with *Format may be generated to export on Google Earth*. Is it an *option* ('may') or a requirement? Would the software have to discover physical locations as well, or would you add that info.

Comment: Why are you mentioning that list of software in the final paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a little less polished than "The Dude", but more flexible and powerful, and much more in keeping with a thesis would be to use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) as your network discovery platform.

- Free
- Runs natively under Linux, Windows & OS-X
- Allows multiple types of network discovery and exploration
- Can interface with GNU Plot and other tools to produce graphical output.
- Outputs can be as images, pdf files or Latex.
- Since it is all python based it is simple to set up periodic scans and act as a web server to view the results in near real-time.
- Export as whatever you would like.
- Finger print discovered devices to identify the device types, etc.

Traceroute Example Plots:
[image: GraphViz output]
[image: 3D Output]

Answer (score 0):

I have always used [The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude) for this sort of thing, albeit on a smaller scale than you seem to have in mind.

[image]    [image]

- automatic discover devices on network in my college - "will automatically scan all devices within specified subnets, draw and layout a map of your networks, monitor services of your devices and alert you in case some service has problems"
- Map network must be designed so that it can be continuously updated and edited - "Allows you to draw your own maps and add custom devices"
- Software can work on Windows or Ubuntu - NO . Sorry, Windows only, but most things work well enough with Wine
- Format may be generated to export on Google Earth - NO, I don't think so, but you can contact them and ask
- should contain computers, laptops, switches, routers, printers in network - "will automatically scan all devices ..."
- Software like ... - I didn't understand this part :-(

> Some of it's features:
>
> ```
> The Dude is free of charge!
> Auto network discovery and layout
> Discovers any type or brand of device
> Device, Link monitoring, and notifications
> Includes SVG icons for devices, and supports custom icons and backgrounds
> Easy installation and usage
> Allows you to draw your own maps and add custom devices
> Supports SNMP, ICMP, DNS and TCP monitoring for devices that support it
> Individual Link usage monitoring and graphs
> Direct access to remote control tools for device management
> Supports remote Dude server and local client
> Runs in Linux Wine environment, MacOS Darwine, and Windows
> Best price/value ratio compared to other products (free of charge)
> ```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Software like - I thought to programs such as op manager, solarwinds NPM, prtg network monitor, lanstate pro, anturis in Windows, cheops-ng, opennms in Ubuntu. How to connect routers, switches... with lines between in Dude?